# beautifulsoup ignores a whitespace

Tags: python-3.x, beautifulsoup

Lets say I have `Hello world.` (There is a white space before Hello) as input and I run:

```
soup = bs(input, "lxml")
```

The initial white space before `Hello world.` is ignored in output. How can I retain whitespace before the above input ?

I tried other parsers like `xml, html.parser`. But, for me `lxml` works absolutely fine except for this scenario.

If anyone can suggest on how to avoid this, it will be helpful.

Example:

```
>>> from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
>>> soup = bs(' Hello world.', "lxml")
>>> soup.p
<p>Hello world.</p>
>>> print(soup)
<html><body><p>Hello world.</p></body></html>
```

Comment: `bs4.BeautifulSoup()` **WILL** keep the white space. It is your example that is flawed.

Comment: @accdias could you please elaborate and suggest ?

Comment: Just try `soup = bs('<p> Hello world.<p>', 'lxml')` and you will see the space will be there. In other words, when you parse the actual web page, any existing spaces inside the content of any tag will be preserved.

Comment: Or even better `soup = bs('<p> Hello world.<p>No trailing space here', 'lxml')` and then `soup.find_all('p')`.

Answer (score 0):

you will have to put your string in the `<p> or <pre>` tag to retain the space.

Code should be like this -

```
>>> from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
>>> soup = bs('<p> Hello world.</p>', "lxml")
>>> soup.p
<p> Hello world.</p>
>>> print(soup)
<html><body><p> Hello world.</p></body></html>
```

Comment: But, that is not a generic way to handle the scenario. I may get some examples with white space and without white space as well..